# Confusion about Hajós construction?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haj%C3%B3s_construction#The_construction) on the Hajós construction. I've tried to execute it in a small graph to see it's results, I guess it would be something like this:

These are the incidency matrices of $G,H$ and the matrix after the equal sign is the result after applying Hajós construction. $!$ is the operation of Hajós construction between two graphs.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
{}&{e_1}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{a}&{1}&{1}&{}\\ 
{b}&{1}&{}&{1}\\ 
{c}&{}&{1}&{1}
\end{bmatrix}_{[G]} ! \begin{bmatrix}
{}&{e_1}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{a}&{1}&{1}&{}\\ 
{b}&{1}&{}&{1}\\ 
{c}&{}&{1}&{1}
\end{bmatrix}_{[H]}  = \begin{bmatrix}
{}&{e_1}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{bmatrix}_{[G!H]} $$

Then taking edges $vw,xy$ in the graphs, I'd select $v,x$ and transform them in a single vertex  and then erase $vw,xy$. Then it would become:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
{}&{\emptyset}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{a}&{}&{1}&{}\\ 
{b}&{}&{}&{1}\\ 
{c}&{}&{1}&{1}
\end{bmatrix}_{[G]} ! \begin{bmatrix}
{}&{\emptyset}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{a}&{}&{1}&{}\\ 
{b}&{}&{}&{1}\\ 
{c}&{}&{1}&{1}
\end{bmatrix}_{[H]}  = \begin{bmatrix}
{}&{e_1}&{e_2}&{e_3}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}\\ 
{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{bmatrix}_{[G!H]} $$

The problem is that I have no idea on how $[G!H]$ should be. I see that the move I made here will create another vertex in $[G!H]$ but I have no idea on what will be the edges. I've tried to execute the process and the edges disappeared completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand the Hajós construction in terms of edges and vertices first. The WIKI article is clear and elementary, so you should be able to understand it.

You will see that the Hajós construction is just a union with one vertex identification, one edge addition and two edge removals.

Now you can start translating this into incidence matrices.
Your specific example seems to apply the construction to two triangles.
The result will then have 5 edges (columns) and 5 rows (vertices).

Note that in general the result very much depends on the chosen edges and vertices, so you will not be able to 'compute' the result matrix when you only know the two input matrices. In that sense your example of two triangles is a bad one, because there is too much symmetry.

Comment: Thanks. I also read a bit of the *Handbook of Graph Theory* and discovered that the construction doesn't have to be made on all edges/vertices. [It seems one could choose a limited ammount of them to process.](http://i.imgur.com/XTRqHnc.png)

Comment: The construction 'uses' 2 graphs, one vertex and three edges as described. Of course you then can apply the construction on the result you get and another graph. The reference you give describes that the construction can be used as part of a process.